# Feature selection for string columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I tried sklearn [SelectKBest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) for feature selection (feature scores) of supervised machine learning before. It looks good, but can only take **numbers** as inputs.

Although I can present some string columns into numbers, for examples:

- Max/min length of strings
- nunique of different strings, etc.

I still hope there's a feature selection method to read strings as input.

Please recommend some feature selection that be able to analyze string (*remark) columns. Or Python import xxx.

- remark: Or maybe some special kinds of strings, e.g., IP addresses, web URL.

Comment: Normally string columns are encoded as they are most often classification columns. What kind are yours as in what data do they represent and how do believe this will effect the output

Comment: @Tasty: for example, i break a full URL columns into several columns of partial URL components (e.g, root domain, 1st /, 2nd /, etc) , can take these string columns into feature selection. This is just one example. i have other columns such as IP address

Comment: So assuming all the URL's are from the same site then you could encode them aka...
/home/gallery/dog --> 1,1,1
/home/gallery/cat --> 1,1,2
/home/about --> 1, 2, 0
/home --> 1, 0, 0
/ --> 0, 0, 0

Comment: @Tasty213: after encode, they are still strings? what kind of encoding scheme?

Comment: After encoding they become integers, for instance you could asign each possibility for each section of the URL an integer

Comment: @Tasty213: so each group of identical strings has the same integer value. i see. this is a method. e.g., IP address should have max 256^4 different possibilities/integers

Comment: Yes but you could limit the resoloution or change the ip adresses into something more usefull (like the ip reigon)

Comment: @Tasty213: so, for what u know, except encoding, there's no method to read strings directly?

Comment: ML and AI models won't read strings in, even high level text/sentiment analysis algorithms convert them internally

Comment: @Tasty213: ok, i see